# Android String Edit and Array's value positioning

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have two problem. Please try to solve...

**No 1.**
Suppose I have two string:-

```
String one = "Android is awesome";
String two = "Android is";
```

Now my question is, can I get **awesome** by comparing those two string like we do with **int**.

```
int abc = 50;
int def = 35;
int ghi = abc - def;
```

output :-

```
ghi = 15;
```

So, this is what we do basically with **int, long, double...** Is it possible also with `String?`

**No 2.**
Now, suppose again I have a **string-array**

```
ArrayList<String> list = new Arraylist()<>;
list.add("beautiful");
list.add("awesome");
list.add("cool");
```

Now, if **string-comparing** is possible, then suppose I have got a new String **three** from comparing **one** and **two**.

So, here,

```
String three = "awesome";
```

Now, again, I am using **if-statement**

```
if(list.contains("awesome")){

**Problem here starts. See the commented texts**

//Here if **awesome** is found in **list**, so can I get the position of **awesome** in the **list**?
}
```

**Forgive me for a big and rough question. Please help me. I am really so sad with this problem.**

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. But if you want to get position of certain element in list you can use `indexOf` method of `ArrayList`  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

Comment: i don't understand your first question. What is suppose to be the result of "Android is awesome" - "Android is" ? Awesome ? Or another thing ? 
For the second question, use methods contains and indexOf of Arralist

Comment: And is it possible to complete two string and get the value?

Comment: I mean, I want to compare those two string one and two and get the result into another string mamed three

Comment: yes yes. I want the result of "Android is awesome" - "Android is"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the remaining string by comparing two strings, try the following

```
String one = "Android is awesome";
String two = "Android is";
    if(one.contains(two)){
        Log.i("remaining string ",one.split(two)[0].replace(" ",""));
        Log.i("remaining string ",one.split(two)[1].replace(" ",""));
    }else{
        Log.i("remaining string ","");
    }
```

Then use the remaining string to find the index from list.Try the following ,

```
  list.indexOf(remainingstring);
```

Comment: Glad it helps. But check for the splitted array. You may get the remaining string at 0 or 1 st position. So be careful with that.

Comment: Thanks for your care. Best of luck